# Discord method that kicks someone after a certain message was typed. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, methods, bots, discord

```
const member = message.guild.member(user);

bot.on('ready', ()=> {
    console.log('Bot reinitialized.');
})

bot.on('message', message => {
            if (message.content === "test") {
                member.kick();
            }

        }
    )
```

So basically I want something like this. After someone typed test the person should be kicked from the discord server.

Comment: What is `user`? And I would think that you'd be wanting to kick the person who typed the message, not who you got on the first line

Comment: I saw this const member online on discord.js. I thought it would work but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to kick who typed the message, you won't need the first line and would replace `member` with the author of the message which is `message.member`

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
      if (message.content === "test") {
            message.member.kick();
      }
});
```

Comment: This error pops up: https://pastebin.com/PCZdwtnx

I think it should work after the error is fixed.

Comment: This error is happening due to one of two things. The bot does not have permissions when it was invited into your server OR you are testing it yourself and are the owner of the server. It cannot kick the owner but if you use an alt or a mate  to try it, it should work. If you want to catch this error just make a check that `message.member` isn't the owner of the guild

Comment: @DemonSlayer21412 That's great! Glad to help